# Calculating the value with large exponents

Tags: exponentiation

I'm trying to solve $2014^{2015}$ $\pmod {11}$, is there a trick or tip to break the problem down to make it easier to solve?

Comment: What do you mean by solve? To simplify it?

Comment: Is there a method to solve it without a calculator?

Comment: What do you mean by *"solve it"*?

Comment: I guess you really want something along the lines of $2014^{2015} \bmod m$?

Comment: I actually made a mistake and forgot the modulus, I edited it

Comment: Then note that $a\equiv b \pmod{m} \implies a^k \equiv b^k\pmod{m}$ for all $k$, and recall Fermat's (so-called little) theorem.

Comment: @DanielFischer:  In this case, Fermat's little theorem is overkill.

Comment: @RossMillikan Yeah, I only looked at the remainder of $2014$ modulo $11$ after I wrote the comment. But since in general, that's useful, I've left it stand.

Comment: To show a modulus in $\LaTeX$, you can use \pmod {modulus}.  You don't need the braces for a single digit.  It gets you the font and the parentheses.

Answer (score 1):

Your result will have $6658$ digits in base $10$.  [Alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=2014%5E2015) seems up to the task, but I got tired of clicking on More Digits.  Are you sure you don't want this modulo some number?

Now that you added the $\pmod {11}$, it becomes much easier.  Note that $2014 \equiv 1 \pmod {11}$

Comment: The answer can be attained with very little calculation.

Comment: @NovaDenizen:  The $\pmod {11}$ was not there when this answer was written.  I have accounted for it now.

Comment: How would I solve this without a calculator or Alpha

Comment: In the specific case here, you have $1^{2015}$, which is easy.  If the base is not $1$, you use [Euler's theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_theorem) to reduce the exponent modulo $\phi(n)$, Euler's totient function of the modulus.  In this case, $\phi(11)=1, 2015 \equiv 5 \pmod {10}$, so the exponent becomes $5$

Answer (score 1):

It's important to remember that if $a \equiv b \mod m$ then $a \cdot c \equiv b \cdot c \mod m$.  From this you can prove if $a \equiv b \mod m$ then $a^c \equiv b^c \mod m$.

So what is the remainder of 2014 divided by 11?

Comment: 183 is the remainder

Comment: @ChetSteadman No, 183 is the quotient.

Comment: woops I meant remainder is less than 1

Comment: @ChetSteadman No, the remainder is not less than 1.

Comment: okay I'm tracking now, 2014 Mod 11 = 1. What is the next step?

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to do this efficiently on a computer or something, you can use a binary expansion of $2015$ to calculate the number.

$$2015 = 1 + 2 + 4 + 8 + 16 + 64 + 128 + 256 + 512 + 1024$$

thus

$$x^{2015} = x\cdot x^2\cdot x^4\cdot x^8\cdot x^{16}\cdot x^{64}\cdot x^{128}\cdot x^{256}\cdot x^{512}\cdot x^{1024}$$

This method is much faster than $x \cdot x \cdot x \cdots $.

Comment: Your answer misses a much easier method.

Comment: The original question didn't have any moduli.